# Parsing json string into dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a nested json string as follows:

```
[{'id': 'tfghnbkivbgdcse',
  'authorization': None,
  'operation_type': 'in',
  'card': {'type': 'debit',
   'brand': 'mastercard',
   'address': None,
   'card_number': '123456XXXXXX7890',
   'holder_name': 'aaaa bbbb’,
   'expiration_year': '21',
   'expiration_month': '11',
   'bank_name': 'XXXXBANK',
   'bank_code': '000'},
  'status': 'failed',
  'creation_date': '2018-06-30T23:59:16-05:00',
  'error_message': 'Bank authorization is required for this charge',
  'order_id': '1743790',
  'amount': 2668.0,
  'currency': 'USD',
  'customer': {'name': 'AAAA',
   'last_name': 'BBBB',
   'email': 'XXXX_1234@outlook.com',
   'phone_number': '1234567890',
   'address': None,
   'creation_date': '2018-06-30T23:59:17-05:00',
   'external_id': None,
   'clabe': None},
  'fee': {'amount': 0.95, 'tax': 0.152, 'currency': 'USD'}}]
```

I want to convert json string into data frame. I have used `json_normalize` from `pandas.io.json`, but I am getting an error.

Comment: Maybe because `None` is invalid type in JSON format?

Comment: That's not JSON

Answer (score 0):

It works if you:

- Change all None to "None"
- Change `'aaaa bbbb’ to 'aaaa bbbb'` (The last character was a different single quote character)
- Change all <'> to <">

It's probably just the quote character you need to fix, if the json data is part of python code.

```
In [39]: ord("'")
Out[39]: 39
In [40]: ord("’")
Out[40]: 8217
```